# Validation errors on nested models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create server-side validations for nested models. Here are my Ember models:

```
//models/blog.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  "name": DS.attr('string'),
  "category": DS.belongsTo('category'),
  "posts": DS.hasMany('post')
});

 //models/category.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  "name": DS.attr('string')
});

 //models/post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  "text": DS.attr('string')
});
```

When saving *blog* model, I validate all the child models as well.

How should I format ember-friendly error JSON when there is a validation error on one of the child models' attribute?

this is a JSON I produce right now when blog's title is invalid:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "title": "name",
      "detail": "some error"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you validate each child model as you save them? So validate child models individually, then validate parent model.

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but how should a response JSON look like with child's errors so that ember data understands it? Because right now, ember data thinks that all validation errors belong to the parent object (object being actually saved) - so even though, child models are invaild, only parent model will be "take the blame" and will be marked as invalid

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: no, I abandoned ember-data validation errors altogether - I "manually" mark model as not valid